# Having error message on creating a module in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm starting to learn Python and I find it really interesting.  I am trying to create my own module and I ran into a bump. The code goes like this:

```
def break_words(sentence):
    words = sentence.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words (words):                                                                             
    sort_word=sorted(words)
    return sort_word
```

The second function has argument `words` fed in by the first, and I think it should work since it has been returned, but on running `filename.sort_words(words)` in Python, it gives an error message of `NameError:global name 'words' is not defined`.  And it's requiring me to define words like `words=filename.break_words(sentence)` before it runs the second function.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please don't forget about correct code indenting here. It really improves visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to explain yourself better in future, it's very confusing to read and probably the reason nobody replied.
This is what I think you want to know:

```
import filename
words = filename.break_words('some sentence goes here')
print filename.sort_words(words)
```

Have you tried that?

edit:
Variables in Python are always defined in scopes, so defining one variable in a function means that it is not defined anywhere outside the function. 
'return' simply returns the value of that variable to the caller.

Comment: Yes .It worked but I am trying to get a way of me not assigning value to words again in python since it has already been assigned under break_words function and I've returned its value to be used automatically by sort_words(words).Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the use of return command

Comment: I Understand what it does now